# Recall data from database one time only

Tags: php, database

i am now setting a kind of payment gateway in my site and actually i am doing the payment confirmation a manual process and here's my idea 
- first the customer will go through check out and complete the payment

- a success page will appear after payment is completed with customer no. and pin code which he will copy it to the customer support to confirm his payment
- customer no. and pin code are recalled from a specified database which also customer support has it
- the complication is : 
  that i want the data recalled to be one time only; to recall one row in a time and never recall it back and move to the next row with the next customer , recalling can be done , but one time only and moving to the next row ? any ideas ?

i know that seems pretty complicated but it's a suitable method for me for now.

Comment: delete that row after its selected once. just make suer it has a proper unique id;. or mark it as `used` add an int field and update it after its been selected

Comment: i think now we have two options
1- to delete the row after its selected once and recalled but is that can be done with php ? i think it need alot of work
 
2- to tag the selected row with "USED" by updating the database and prevent any row with "USED' to be recalled anymore . i think this is more applicable 

but it's still in general take phase .. i hope to find some approving and support regarding how that could be done 
and thanks for your answer Dagon

Comment: either an update query or a delete query after the select, you decide